# Is The Fall movie based on real events?

Tags: the-fall

In the end of the movie The Fall (2006) there are several black-and-white scenes shown from (I suppose) old comedy movies with humorous stunts and such. The movie itself is centered around a man who suffered a trauma while performing a stunt. So I was wondering if the movie is somehow about a famous stuntman. It seems as if it is, but I don't think there is a particular name mentioned in the movie, except all the main characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The movie is not based on real events, but is a retelling of the 1981 Bulgarian film [Yo Ho Ho](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278827/) (which itself is an original story).

The Fall is incredibly realistic feeling at times, one of the reasons of which can be derived from a quick look at its [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fall_%282006_film%29#Production):

> [The director's audio commentary] reveal that actor Lee Pace remained in
>   a bed for most of the early filming at the director's suggestion,
>   convincing most of the crew that he was in fact unable to walk. The
>   intention, Tarsem and Pace noted, was to maximize the realism of Roy's
>   physical limitations in the eyes of Catinca Untaru, whose lines and
>   reactions as the character Alexandria were largely unscripted, and so
>   were young Catinca's spontaneous interactions with Pace's character.
>   For example, Alexandria's misinterpreting the letter E as the number 3
>   in a note written by Roy came about from an accidental misreading by
>   the 6-year-old actress during filming, which the director then
>   realized he could adapt into a clever twist in the story.
>
> To further the realism of young Catinca's performance, Tarsem had
>   portions of the hospital scenes between Pace and his young co-star
>   filmed through small holes in the hospital bed curtains, maximizing
>   the youngster's spontaneous interactions with Pace despite the
>   presence of the film crew surrounding them.

I feel this, coupled with the shots towards the end of the film of some of the most dangerous stunts in silent films, make it seem like it was a real story - but alas, there doesn't appear to be any evidence to suggest it is.